# UML representation of Java Enum

Tags: java, enums, uml

I am creating a UML class diagram for a Java Enum with multiple values. Example:

```
public enum ExtractType {
      Type1 ("Value1", "Value2"),
      Type2 ("Value1", "Value2"),
      ...
}
```

Does the UML specification say anything about including values while drawing an Enum class diagram?  Or is it as simple as below?

```
    +---------------------+
    |   <<enumeration>>   |
    |     ExtractType     |
    +---------------------+
    |        Type1        |
    |        Type2        |
    |        .....        |
    +---------------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uml class diagram enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412944/uml-class-diagram-enum)

Comment: @Trobbins I have read this post before asking the question, my question is different than this one

Comment: It would just be as simple as you've shown. 
Here is another resource: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your example is perfectly fine. It's described in many places in
 [UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/):
[image]