# UML class diagrams (operations compartment)

Tags: c++, class, uml, diagram

What should be written in the operations compartment? Shall it contain function definitions and/or function calls?

Also, how to represent `enum` and `structures` in `class diagram`?

Comment: You should post what you have tried . It might help for better answers

Comment: See also http://www.uml-diagrams.org/operation.html and http://www.uml-diagrams.org/data-type.html#enumeration

Answer (score 5):

Class diagrams operational block contains operations to classes and interfaces. It must be function definition and not function call. 
For enum representation in class diagram refer to [UML class diagram enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412944/uml-class-diagram-enum)

Comment: can you explain how to find which functions are performing operations to interfaces

Comment: yes I have a source code in C++, I just designed UML class diagram using star UML tool. I want to know how to find and draw the interfaces in that class diagram

Comment: An interface must have at least one class to implement it. In UML, an interface is considered to be a specialization of a class modeling element. Therefore, an interface is drawn just like a class, but the top compartment of the rectangle also has the text "«interface»". Something like: